# Decryption using Python

Tags: python, encryption

I am getting a string private key and String which is to be decrypted.

It is being encrypted using `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-512ANDMGF1PADDING")`

I tried using the below code, but it fails with: ValueError: `Ciphertext length must be equal to key size.`

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa, padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes

encrypted_message = 'MTEyMw=='
private_key_str = """-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEA4v3 ...L8Q9xNBVn9XJ5 -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"""

private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
    private_key_str.encode(),
    password=None,
    backend=default_backend()
)

decrypted = private_key.decrypt(
    encrypted_message,
    padding.OAEP(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        label=None
    )
)

print(decrypted.decode())
```

Comment: Well, what does the `encrypted_message` look like? For instance, if it's base64 encoded, chances are you'd need to `base64.decode()` it first.

Comment: Updated the code on how the string and key looks like

Comment: The digest is inconsistent: in the Java code you use SHA-512, in the Python code SHA-256.

Comment: In the Python code, try SHA-512 for the OAEP hash and SHA-1 for the MGF1 hash (the SunJCE provider defaults for MGF1 to SHA-1) and if that doesn't work, use SHA-512 for the MGF1 hash as well (that's how the BC provider does it).

Answer (score 0):

Right, if your message looks like

```
encrypted_message = 'MTEyMw=='
```

it means it's Base64 encoded. (That's still a very short message, I'll just assume you've truncated it for display here.)

Pass it through `base64.decode()` first:

```
decrypted = private_key.decrypt(
    base64.decode(encrypted_message),
    # ...
```

Comment: Edited the code to: base64.b64decode(encrypted_message), Now it is giving Encryption/decryption failed.

Comment: So i'm not wondering if i'm using the right decryption method. Any help would be really appreciated.